# How can I stop an event from propagating in IE11 using JQuery UI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, event-handling, internet-explorer-11

I am using jquery-ui-1.8.21 autocomplete library to create dropdowns for the fields in my form. Autocomplete comes with 2 event handlers, 'select' and 'change'.

When a user selects an item from the dropdown it triggers the 'select' event, populating the field, adding text to a field (lets call it field B), and other things. When a user unfocuses a field, the 'change' event is triggered if the value in the field was changed, adding text to field B.

My problem is that when a user selects an item in a dropdown and then unfocuses, it triggers both the 'select' and 'change' events, adding text to field B twice. I want to only trigger the select event in order to add the text once. For some reason both events only trigger when I click on the dropdown, when I select using the keyboard only 'select' is triggered.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    console.log("select function")
    //other stuff
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

change: function (event, ui) {
    console.log("change function")
    //other stuff
}
```

I have tried `event.preventDefault`, `event.returnValue`, both of those in every combination with `window.event` and `event.originalEvent` (since JQuery creates its own event), and `return false` and none of them stop the 'change' event from triggering.

Interestingly for all those events `event.cancelable` and `event.isDefaultPrevented` read as true, so it SHOULD be canceling, but it isn't.

How can I get this to work?

This is only an issue in IE11, in Chrome `event.preventDefault` works fine.

Comment: What is the actual higher level problem it creates?

Comment: @charlietfl Both events add text to a field. If both events trigger, the text get added twice which is incorrect.